# Transaction to smart contract failing when calling it from my Next js front end

Tags: next.js, transactions, smartcontracts

If I call a variable to my smart contract deployed on mumbai from my next js front end, everything works fine. But when I execute a transaction, I have an error.
Here is the code executed on the front end:

```js
await myContract.methods.bidding(bid)
                .send({ 
                  from: accounts[0], 
                  gas: gasLimit, 
                  gasPrice: gasPrice })
                .on('transactionHash', (hash) => { console.log("transaction hash: ", hash ) })
                .on('confirmation', (confirmationNumber, receipt) => { console.log("confirmation & receipt : ", confirmationNumber, receipt) })
                .on('error', (error) => { console.log("error: ", error) });
```

and here is the error I get:

> error:  TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:.............

I am stuck in this for days....